# Type class with conversion from a given type

Tags: haskell

I would like to implement a class with a function conv that converts from a given T type.
The pseudo-code (that doesn't compile) would look like this:

```
data T a b c d  = List [a] | Tup1 a | Tup2 a b | Tup3 a b c deriving (Show)

class ConvT t where
  conv :: T a b c d -> t

instance ConvT [a] where
  conv (List x) = x

instance ConvT (a,b) where
  conv (Tup2 a b) = (a,b)
```

How can I do that?
Note that I don't plan to use that in production -- I'm just interested in understanding the Haskell type system more.

Comment: Are you familiar with pattern matching?  It sounds like that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that this does not make much sense, since you are trying to define a a family of functions that are each inhernetly partial.  It can be done though, it just requires extensions.

solution 1: MPTC

```
class ConvT a b c d t where
  conv :: T a b c d -> t

instance ConvT a b c d [a] where
  conv (List x) = x

instance ConvT a b c d (a,b) where
  conv (Tup2 a b) = (a,b)
```

solution 2: constraint kinds and type families.

```
class ConvT t where
  type ConvC t a b c d :: Constraint
  conv :: ConvC t a b c d => T a b c d -> t

instance ConvT [a] where
  type ConvC [a] a' b c d = a ~ a'
  conv (List x) = x

instance ConvT (a,b) where
  type ConvC (a,b) a' b' c d = (a ~ a', b ~ b')
  conv (Tup2 a b) = (a,b)
```

note: this code is not tested but gets the idea across.  Also, don't do this.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm not planning to do this but in my case having such a conv function would save me a lot of pattern matching. I need to get some data wrapped into a ctor of the T type at the beginning of different functions I'm calling. It's cumbersome and using the conv function would infer the right unwrapping - and throw and error if the type it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your typeclass promises that you can convert `(T a b c d)` into `t`, for any types `a b c d t`. But the instance declarations only work if there's some correspondence between the types. For example, the `List` case only works if `t` is `[a]`, so it is not a valid instance of the typeclass you defined.

I'm not a Haskell expert, but I think this is impossible, simply because there is no way to write a correct type signature for `conv`.